# <font> tag deprecated now so what is the correct way

Tags: html, fonts

I have an old version of frontpage I am toying around with.  I planned to use django in the background to do the heavy lifting but thought using this old Frontpage software I have would be good for the front end but I am finding it is writing code in an out of date fashion. I was reading that the  tag has been deprecated and we should be using "style" now.  the example I was reading has it inside the paragraph

or header  tag.  However the code I have from frontpage is using the font tag inside of a table cell tag so I am wondering what is the correct way to write it.

Here is the code generated by Frontpage

```
<td width="190" align="center" bgcolor="#000080" height="18"><b><a  href="index.htm">
    <font title="return to main page" color="#00FFFF" face="Verdana">Home</font></a></b></td>
```

would I just change it so the styles

```
<td width="190" align="center" bgcolor="#000080" height="18" style="color:#00FFFF;font-family:Verdana">
<b><a  href="index.htm">Home</a></b>
</td>
```

My problem with that is now all text in the table cell would be that font right?  So if I wanted more things in the table cell than just the link where would I put that?  Also I just tried that and the font-family is working but not the color...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using inline styles like you've posted, this would work.

```
<td style="width: 190px; height: 18px; text-align: center; background-color: #000080;">
     <a href="index.htm" style="color: #00FFFF; font-family: Verdana;"><strong>Home</strong></a>
</td>
```

As a side note, you have several very bad practices. Using tables to lay out your website is very outdated and hard to work with (which is why it is outdated). Using inline CSS is confusing to everyone (including yourself). In addition to the references others have posted, I recommend http://htmldog.com/

Comment: like I said this was auto generated code from a version of Frontpage I bought in like 2002 or something like that.  I don't write it that way.  I just wanted to try out that program because I have it.  I am trying to compare this to what the modern methods are so I understand better.

Comment: That is also kinda funny because I always thought using tables was stupid.  I just have never done much web development so I don't know much of how it has changed since I was in school in the 90's...I have spent my career writing machine code for embedded systems.  My next project is the sensor firmware for a new windows 8 tablet (gyro, accelerometers, compass...) so all this web stuff is goofy to me... ;)

Comment: Oh yea, I didn't mean to imply that your practices are consciously bad so much as your code (from Frontpage) has bad practices in it. Web practices have been totally reinvented in the past ten years (which is probably the last time Frontpage got a new version). A modern alternative for computer generated front ends would be Adobe Dreamweaver, but the best way to make websites will always be by hand.

Comment: yea no problemo I hear ya.  That is really what this question is about.  I have started a new business on the side that needs a web site.  I have been programming for more than 20 years but never touched the web.  I remembered I had this old tool so I tried it out.  When I got to a few sticking points (needed a backed database...) I talked with a buddy who turned me on to Django.  When I got done with a few different Django tutorials I went back and started in on some basic HTML tutorials because I realized how much I didn't actually know.  Then I looked at my Frontpage code and here we are.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look up and spend some time learning CSS.
You can do something like this with it:

CSS:

```
.linkstyle
{
   font-family: verdana;
   color: #00FFFF;
}
```

CODE:

```
<span style="linkstyle"><a href="index.htm">Home</a></span>
```

Comment: Although, you could add the class directly to the link. Or if you want all links to look the same, then you won't need a class, just make the selector simply 'a', but don't forget about 'a:hover', etc.

Comment: True. Adding the class separately is better design assuming it will be used for multiple links. I had forgotten about just using 'a'. D'oh!

Comment: Using spans and divs when not needed is just as ugly as inline styles. Blech!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Frontpage?

Grab a free editor (search for one), or just create it yourself using something like Notepad++. The amount of time you will spend cleaning up code will be a total waste of your time when using Frontpage (gui).

Also use CSS styles instead of inline bgcolor / font, etc;

Comment: Because I have it.  I agree I don't think I want to use it but I wanted to try it out.  I bought it a long time ago for my wife to have for a class she took in her masters program and I never got around to playing with it.  I wanted to try it out but I think it is a waste of time.

Comment: By the way I do use a different editor, VI (GVIM), for my actual development.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `<span>` tags with `class` attributes and css.

Here are some good references on that stuff:

HTML: http://www.w3schools.com/tags

CSS2: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_reference.asp

CSS3: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_reference.asp

Comment: I am going through the tutorials at that site and that is why I came here with a question.  I got to the section on Fonts and it said the way Frontpage built my website was wrong.  I built a simple site using the Old Frontpage and then started reading the training on the W3 web site and comparing to what Frontpage wrote to see how it is working.  When I teach myself things like programming I don't just follow the tutorials I do 2 or 3 side projects simultaneously to try variations of what I am learning and I absorb it much better than if I follow just what is written.

Comment: I've been using w3schools since a professor showed me it back in my undergrad days and have noticed a number of issues mentioned on w3fools but, unfortunately, have not found a good alternative to it. Thanks for the link!